# parse a structured (structure of machine) text-file (config-file) into a structured table format

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, text, config

main goal is to get from a more or less readable config file into a table format which can be read from everyone witouth deeper understanding of the machine and their configuration standards.

i've got a config file:

```
******A MANO:111111         ,20190726,001,0914,06621242746     
DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1
ST*001*0001
ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0
CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755
PA1*0*100
PA1*1*60
PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0
******E MANO:111111         ,20190726,001,0914,06621242746     
******A MANO:222222         ,20190726,001,0914,06621242746     
DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1
ST*001*0001
ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0
CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755
PA1*0*100
PA1*1*60
PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0
******E MANO:222222         ,20190726,001,0914,06621242746
```

There are several objects in the file always starting with 'A MANO:' and ending with 'E MANO:' followed by the object-number.
all the lines underneath are the attributes of the object (settings of the machine). Not all objects have the same amount of settings. There could be 55 Lines for one object and 199 for another.

what i tried so far:

```
from pyparsing import *

'''
grammar:
object_nr ::= Word(nums, exact=6)
num ::= '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
'''

path_input = r'\\...\...'

with open(path_input) as input_file:
    line = input_file.readline()
    cnt = 1

object_nr_parser = Word(nums, exact=6)

for match, start, stop in object_nr_parser.scanString(input_file):
    print(match, start, stop)
```

which gives me the printout:
    ['201907'] 116 122
    ['019211'] 172 178

the number it founds and the start and ending points in the string. But this numbers are not what I'm looking for nor correct. i can't even find the second number in the config-file.

is it the right way to solve this with pyparsing or is there a more convenient way to do it? Where did i do the mistake?

At the end it would be astounding if i would have an object for every machine with attributes which would be all the lines between the A MANO: and the E MANO:

expected result would be something like this:

```
{"object": "111111",
"line1":"DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1",
"line2":"ST*001*0001",
"line3":"ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0",
"line4":"CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755",
"line5":"PA1*0*100",
"line6":"PA1*1*60",
"line7":"PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0"},
{"object": "222222",
"line1":"DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1",
"line2":"ST*001*0001",
"line3":"ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0",
"line4":"CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755",
"line5":"PA1*0*100",
"line6":"PA1*1*60",
"line7":"PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0",
"line8":"PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0",
"line9":"PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0",
"line10":"PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0"}
```

Not sure if that is the best solution for the purpose but it's the one that came into mind at this point.

One of the dirtiest ways to get the thing done would be using regex and replace the MANO with line break and all the line breaks with ';'. I don't think that this would be a solution one should use

Comment: Can you add expected result?

Comment: @Alderven of course i added the "expected" result as it came into my mind for now. not sure if that is the best way to store the data for further processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it line by line:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

result = []
name = ''
i = 1
for line in lines:
    if 'A MANO' in line:
        name = re.findall('A MANO:(\d+)', line)[0]
        result.append({'object': name})
        i = 1
    elif 'E MANO' not in line:
        result[-1][f'line{i}'] = line
        i += 1
```

Output:

```
[{
        'object': '111111',
        'line1': 'DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1',
        'line2': 'ST*001*0001',
        'line3': 'ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0',
        'line4': 'CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755',
        'line5': 'PA1*0*100',
        'line6': 'PA1*1*60',
        'line7': 'PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0'
    }, {
        'object': '222222',
        'line1': 'DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1',
        'line2': 'ST*001*0001',
        'line3': 'ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0',
        'line4': 'CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755',
        'line5': 'PA1*0*100',
        'line6': 'PA1*1*60',
        'line7': 'PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0'
    }
]
```

But I suggest using more compact output format:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

result = {}
name = ''
for line in lines:
    if 'A MANO' in line:
        name = re.findall('A MANO:(\d+)', line)[0]
        result[name] = []
    elif 'E MANO' not in line:
        result[name].append(line)
```

Output:

```
{
    '111111': ['DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1', 'ST*001*0001', 'ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0', 'CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755', 'PA1*0*100', 'PA1*1*60', 'PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0'],
    '222222': ['DXS*HAWA776A0A*VA*V0/6*1', 'ST*001*0001', 'ID1*HAW250755*VMI1-9900****250755*6*0', 'CB1*021545*DeBright*7.030.16*3.02*250755', 'PA1*0*100', 'PA1*1*60', 'PA2*2769*166140*210*12600*0*0*0*0']
}
```

Comment: for what is the re? -> i do get an error 'set' object does not support item assignment -> was some typo, now it is running properly, thanks =)

Comment: Whats the benefit of using your second shorter form? looks like it is more difficult to get the single values from the objects out of the list for further processing

Comment: It is shorter - that's the benefit :)